# arrow with triangle tail

Tags: arrows, scaling, stmaryrd

I'd like to have an arrow shape with a triangle tail, which goes along well with`\rightarrowtriangle` from the `stmaryrd` package. Using `\smalltriangleright\!\!\!\to` with `\smalltriangleright` from `MnSymbol` goes in the right direction, but the triangle is a bit large, and also using the negative spaces doesn't work well with scaling. How can I rescale the triangle, get the spacing right, and bundle the result up in a robust way? Or is there an easier solution? See example below.

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{stmaryrd}
\usepackage{MnSymbol}
\begin{document}

$A\rightarrowtriangle B$

$A\mathrel{\smalltriangleright\!\!\!\to} B$

$\scriptstyle A\mathrel{\smalltriangleright\!\!\!\to} B$
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that `\smalltriangleright` is an binary operation symbol and `\to` is a relation symbol, so with

```
\smalltriangleright\!\!\!\to
```

TeX will treat `\smalltriangleright` as an ordinary symbol, in this context, and add the standard space between an ordinary and a relation symbols, but not in script style. You might do

```
\nonscript\!\nonscript\!\nonscript\!
```

instead, or, better, `\nonscript\mkern-9mu`. But there's a better strategy: make `\smalltriangleright` a relation symbol and insert a small backing up again as a relation.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{stmaryrd}
\usepackage{MnSymbol}

\newcommand{\rightarrowtriangletail}{
  \mathrel\smalltriangleright
  \mathrel{\!}
  \rightarrow
}

\begin{document}

$A \rightarrowtriangle B$

$A \rightarrowtriangletail B$

$\scriptstyle A \rightarrowtriangletail B$

\end{document}
```

[image]

However, I usually recommend against using `MnSymbol` that changes all symbols into shapes studied for going along with Minion. Better to just import the needed symbols (this has already been treated on the site).

Comment: Thanks so much! Do you also happen to know how I can make the tail triangle a bit smaller, so it matches the size of the triangle in \rightarrowtriangle?